# Displaying random numbers starting with zero cipher in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, math, random, numbers

I'm working on a random pin generating project with JavaScript and I want to generate random pins like `0351`, `0947`, `0268` using `Math.random()` method, where the pin will start with the `0` cipher and the zero will be displayed in the output.

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you provide some examples of what do you expect from output and what not?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually with Math.random(), we can generate random numbers but when there is a number like 0345 the zero isn't displayed. I want the zero to be displayed in the output.

Comment: Prefix the randomly generated number with zero i.e var r='0'+ your randomly generated number

Answer (score 0):

You can display them as strings like this:

```js
var pin = "0";
function randompin() {
    for(var i=0;i<3;i++) {
        pin = pin + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10).toString();
    }
    console.log(pin)
}

randompin();
```

So you'll get a 4-digit string starting with zero

Answer (score 0):

Can this help you?

```js
function getRandomPin() {
  return '0' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 900 + 100);
}

console.log(getRandomPin());
console.log(getRandomPin());
console.log(getRandomPin());
```

The bounds of this solution go from `0100` to `0999`

Instead, for the following one, I added more controls about the numbers that can be generated under `0100`:

```js
function getRandomPin() {
  var temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
  if (temp < 100) {
    if (temp < 10) {
      return '000' + temp;
    }
    else {
      return '00' + temp;
    }
  }
  else {
    return '0' + temp;
  }
}

console.log(getRandomPin());
console.log(getRandomPin());
console.log(getRandomPin());
```

---

**EDIT:** The following is a solution that takes out a number that start with the `0` cipher if the previous outcome was not starting with that digit, as requested by comment:

```js
var bool = false;

function getRandomPin() {
  if (bool) {
    var temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
    bool = false;
  }
  else {
    var temp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
    bool = true;
  }
  
  if (temp < 10) {
    return '000' + temp;
  }
  else if (temp < 100) {
    return '00' + temp;
  }
  else if (temp < 1000) {
    return '0' + temp;
  }
  else {
    return temp;
  }
}

console.log(getRandomPin());
console.log(getRandomPin());
console.log(getRandomPin());
console.log(getRandomPin());
console.log(getRandomPin());
console.log(getRandomPin());
```

*It's correct to advice that the last solution provides a number that start with `0` every time the previous number is at least `1000`, but this doesn't prevent a `0xyz` number after another `0xyz` one.*

Comment: Thank you all for giving me so helpful answers. It is really awesome to get so many quality answers within such a short time. But I want to know is there any way get these numbers starting with zero randomly? for example that 0568 will generated randomly after 4521? is this possible?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure to understand, but about what I got, you want to receive a number like `0568` exactly after you got a number that does not start with `0`, like `4521`, is this your target?

Comment: xKobalt. Exactly mate.You got my point.

Comment: Ok, I just modified the answer, hope this help you :)

Comment: xKobalt. where is the modified answer mate?

Comment: You can see the edit from **`EDIT:`** label

Comment: okay got it. Thansk alot for the answer mate.

Comment: Always happy to help, but don't forget to upvote and accept :)